# Do I write javadoc comments for each instance variable?

Tags: java, javadoc, checkstyle

```
private String label = "";
private String color = "";
private double edge = 0;

public Dodecahedron(String labelIn, String colorIn, double edgeIn)
```

I am getting an error message stating missing Javadoc comment. [JavadocVariable] (the instance variable lines and [JavadocMethod]

Is there a specific format or syntax I have to write to get rid of these errors?

Comment: I'm running it through Checkstyle as that is required of the course I am taking. We get styling points knocked off for any checkstyle errors.

Comment: Each project team should decide for themselves the level of Javadoc they need and want. It’s very customary to leave Javadoc out for private variables, and private methods too. My style is to include it if I believe there is something the next programmer reading the code needs to know, and leave it out if I find it easy to get enough information from the variable name (method name) and the usage in the code.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it in a single line if that makes it better.

```
/** The session that will be used. */
private CastSession session;
```

Answer (score 5):

Javadoc comments start with `/**` and end with `*/`. It's also customary to start each new line with a `*`. E.g.:

```
/**
 * The label to use.
 */
private String label = "";
```

Comment: So I have to type a multiple comment for each individual instance variable?

Comment: @AndrewT under the checkstyle configuration you seem to be using, yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
/** Description of something. */
```

This is a simple JavaDoc, do not forget to put period at the end of the first line.

You can read more info: https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javadoc-tool.html